# Elm: How does Debug.log work?

Tags: logging, output, elm

I'm logging the `a` and `b` values of a `foldl`.

```
words = ["mate", "bro", "bruv"]

sum2 = List.foldl
    (\a b ->
        Debug.log(toString <| a)
        Debug.log(toString <| b)
        a
    ) "guv" words
```

It works as expected, but I can't understand the output:

```
"mate": <function>
"guv": "mate"
"bro": <function>
"mate": "bro"
"bruv": <function>
"bro": "bruv"
```

Why is it outputting `a` as a `<function>`, and what is it outputting `b` as `a:b` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`Debug.log`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Debug#log) takes two arguments, a tag string, which can be anything, and then the value to be logged. Updating your code like this might work:

```
words = ["mate", "bro", "bruv"]

sum2 = List.foldl
    (\a b 
        Debug.log "Value of a: " a
        Debug.log "Value of b: " b
        a
    ) "guv" words
```

Although, come to think of it, I think you need to do a bit of a trick for logging values that you don't want to return, like so:

```
words = ["mate", "bro", "bruv"]

sum2 = List.foldl
    (\a b ->
        let
            _ = Debug.log "Value of a: " a               
            _ = Debug.log "Value of b: " b
        in
            a
    ) "guv" words
```

Comment: That works, interesting! Is there a rule in Elm that you can't have statements that don't get saved to variable? E.g. `Debug.log "Value of a: " a `  doesn't work without the `logA =`

Comment: Yes, since Elm is (almost) purely functional, you can't have any side-effects, but since `Debug.log` is one of the exceptions to that rule, you still have to trick the Elm compiler. Usually, when you're only logging a single value, you use `_` instead of `logA` to indicate that it's a throw-away variable.

Comment: You can use `_` for both, it actually means throwaway to the compiler, rather than just a value that happens to be named `_` (see an example at https://ellie-app.com/Swtbcn7wNpa1/0)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, that's great.